# C++ virtual variable in inheritance class hierarchy

Tags: c++, templates, variables, virtual

I have a  template class hierarchy,

```
                   ___ Class (ClassA)
                  |
AbstractClass_____

                  |___ Class (ClassB)
```

in classA and ClassB, I have a const NullPosition of a templated type, which is different in ClassA and ClassB. In class classA and ClassB I have to do some operation which are dependant on the value of the NullPosition.

Now I need to do some operations depending on the value on NullPosition, but I am having hard time since the variable are different type and values. To be more specific NullPosition in classA identifies an invalid array index, therefore equals -1;
in classB it identifies a NULL pointer therefore it equals 0.

Please find below an example.

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTCLASS_H
#define  ABSTRACTCLASS_H

template <class T, class P>
class AbstractClass
{
      public: 

      typedef T Type;
      typedef P Position;

      void MethodX() const;
      virtual Position Method() const = 0; 


};

template <class T, class P>
void AbstractClass<T,P>::MethodX() const
{
     Position p=Method();

     /*
     what I am trying to achieve is being able to use the constant NullPosition in abstract class.

     if (p==NullPosition)
     cout<<"p is equal NULLPOSITION";
     else
     cout<<"p is not equal NULLPOSITION";  
     */
}

#endif



#ifndef CLASS_A_H
#define  CLASS_A_H
#include "../AbstractClass.h"

template <class T>
class Class:public AbstractClass<T,unsigned int>
{
      public:

      typedef T Type;
      typedef typename AbstractClass<T,unsigned int>::Position Position;

      Class();

      Position Method() const;  

      static const Position NullPosition=-1;

      private:
              Type* TypeArray;
              unsigned int nElements;

};

      template <class T>
      Class<T>::Class()
      {
       nElements=0;
       TypeArray=new Type[128];
      }

      template <class T>
      typename Class<T>::Position Class<T>::Method() const 
      {

       return NullPosition;

      }

#endif




#ifndef CLASS_B_H
#define CLASS_B_H

#include "../AbstractClass.h"

template <class T>
struct elementNode
{
    typedef T Type;
    typedef elementNode* Position;

    Type element;
    Position nextNode;
};

template <class T>
class Class:public AbstractClass<T, typename elementNode<T>::Position>
{
      public:

      typedef T Type;
      typedef typename AbstractClass<T, typename elementNode<T>::Position>::Position Position;

      Class();
      Position Method() const; 

      static const Position NullPosition;

      private:
              Position root;
              Position lastElement;

};

      template <class T>
      const typename Class<T>::Position Class<T>::NullPosition=0;

      template <class T>
      Class<T>::Class()
      {
       lastElement=root=NullPosition; 
      }

      template <class T>
      typename Class<T>::Position Class<T>::Method() const 
      {

       return NullPosition;

      }

#endif


#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


#include "Class/ClassA/Class.h" 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Class<int> classA;

    classA.MethodX();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please not that ClassA and ClassB share the same name Class, so that I a can use them interchangeble in my code by changing just the include path - #include "Class/ClassA/Class.h" for classA and #include "Class/ClassB/Class.h" for classB.

Comment: Am I the only one that has a cold shiver run up my spine after reading that closing paragraph?

Comment: I have a lot of question on some choices you have made that seem to make this more confusing. Why not use `template <class Type, class Position>` instead of `typedef T Type`.

Comment: Template argument names are not accessible in subclasses.

Comment: To add some context to WhozCraig's shivering: Why would you do something like that? You can already use them interchangeably without that include nonsense using a pointer to their base class, at least if they both derive from some AbstractClass<T,P>. If ClassA and ClassB (i.e. the most derived types) are distinct but are still to be usable interchangeably, you might want to check if your design is flawed or provide a conversion. Otherwise, if you need ClassA, use ClassA, if you need ClassB, use ClassB. Using the same name for distinct types is breathtakingly hurtful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem. You have so many choices:

- Pass NullPosition as a non-type template argument along to the base class.
- Create a traits class that determines the null position for some type. Specialize it before defining the subclasses.
- Add an abstract function to the base class that the subclasses override to return the null position.
- Add an abstract function to the base class that the subclasses override to determine whether a position is the NullPosition.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the entire requirement, but it appears you are trying to do something different on MethodX depending on the type of P.

You could use template specialization on the MethodX function etc. since the second parameter P is different for the two derived classes.

Something like this:

```
template<class T> void MethodX<T,NullPosition>
{
    // Do NullPosition stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something i didn't understand, but if you need a member in the parent class, then why put it in the subclass and not the parent?

Oh, and if you have two classes with same name but different method implementations, only one of the methods will exist after linking. If you want to access both classes using a common name in different source files, use typedefs:

```
class foo1 {.....};
class foo2 {.....};

typedef foo foo1;
// or typedef foo foo2;
```