# C++ - invalid use of undefined type ... - declaration of `class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, declaration

I have classes SuperClass and Subclass, where SubClass is inheriting from SuperClass.

In SuperClass I have a constant property who's values depends on the SubClass using it. Howerver I need it to be declared in SuperClass as there are some other methods in SuperClass using it as well, but I need to initalize it in SubClass as the value of the constant changes depending on the SubClass type instantiated.

From a [previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467376/c-virtual-variable-in-inheritance-class-hierarchy), I know the best solution to this is using a trait class. However using such a solution would involve massive changes to my code. Therefore, I have chosen the approach here shown.

**SuperClass.h**

```
#ifndef SUPERCLASS_H
#define SUPERCLASS_H


#include <string>

template <class T, class P>
class SuperClass
{
      public:

       typedef T type;
       typedef P position;

       static const position NULLPOSITION;

};

#endif
```

**SubClass.h**

```
#ifndef SUBCLASS_H
#define SUBCLASS_H

#include <string>
#include "SuperClass.h"


template <class T>
class SubClass:public SuperClass<T,int>
{

};

template<class T>
const typename SuperClass<T,int>::position SuperClass<T,int>::NULLPOSITION=0;

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "SubClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SubClass<int> subClass;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On compiling I get

```
invalid use of undefined type `class SuperClass<T, int>
```

and

```
declaration of `class SuperClass<T, int>
```

errors.
What might be the issue?

Comment: Please please please please don't call your class Class.

Comment: @Borgleader (Better call it `class class`, `struct class`, `class struct` or `struct struct`, right? :P)

Comment: @Borgleader Ok I have edited the question, accordingly.

Comment: `template<class T, class P> const typename SuperClass<T,P>::position SuperClass<T,P>::NULLPOSITION = 0;` under your SuperClass definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your definition of `NULLPOSITION`. You have declared a static member `NULLPOSITION` for the template `SuperClass`, but have not defined it. Instead, you attempt to define the member for a partial explicit instantiation of it. You should delete the partial explicit instantiation definition, and define a regular template class static member definition for `NULLPOSITION` instead.

To allow subclasses to provide a different initialization value for `NULLPOSITION`, this can be accomplished via a (perhaps optional) template parameter.

```
template <class T, class P, P INIT>
class SuperClass
{
public:
    typedef T type;
    typedef P position;
    static const position NULLPOSITION;
};

template<class T, class P, P INIT>
const typename SuperClass<T,P,INIT>::position
    SuperClass<T,P,INIT>::NULLPOSITION = INIT;

template <class T>
class SubClass:public SuperClass<T,int, 0>
{
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By specializing the way you are, you are not actually instantiating NULLPOSITION (or POSIZIONENULLA, check your code)

**14.7.1.2**

> in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of
>   a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is
>   itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data
>   member to exist

You might want to explicitely define the data member with another class, as in

```
template<typename P>
class PositionClass
{
    public:
        typedef P position;
        static const position NULLPOSITION;
};
template <typename T, class P>
class SuperClass : public PositionClass<P>
{
    public:
        typedef T type;
};

const PositionClass<int>::position  PositionClass<int>::NULLPOSITION = 0;
```